# Mapbox offline storage size

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am using MGLOfflineStorage to download tiles(default style) for offline usage. Downloading very small region takes ~75MB. Downloading much bigger region takes ~100MB, which is strange. So it seems that actual tiles are not that big, and that every region downloads ~70MB of some common data or something(font, icons etc.)? Is this normal?

Is it possible to embed that common data in the app for specific style? Or to make that common data smaller somehow?

EDIT: It seems that this common size for vector tiles depends a lot upon style. I just tested with basic style and it takes ~40MB instead of ~70MB.

I also tested using raster tiles(Satelite style), the conclusion is that using raster tiles is better for smaller areas and using vector tiles is better for bigger areas. This is because raster tiles depend a lot more on area size than vector tiles and raster tiles don't have that initial common download.

So additional question is - is it possible to use street style as raster tiles?

Using ios-v3.2.0-rc.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to minimize the size of the initial resource download would be to limit the number of fonts (and font styles, such as italics) that you use. It’s not currently possible to pre-populate an app with offline data or resources.

Improving the size of font downloads [will be a focus](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/4069) in future releases.

Per the [official doc](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mobile-offline/#network-data-and-disk-space):

> The total size of offline resources will vary from region to region depending on:
>
> - The geographic extent of the region
> - The zoom level range of the region
> - Feature count and density
> - **The sources, fonts, and icons used by the style**
> - The size of individual tiles required by the region
> - Whether the region overlaps with previously downloaded regions
>
> For the default Mapbox Streets style, some typical total sizes are:
>
> - City of Barcelona: 83 MB
> - Greater London within the M25 at zoom levels 0–15: 120 MB
> - Contiguous United States at zoom levels 0–9: 290 MB
>
> For Mapbox Satellite:
>
> - City of Barcelona: 45 MB
> - Greater London within the M25 at zoom levels 0–15: 400 MB
> - Contiguous United States at zoom levels 0–9: 315 MB
>
> **Note that these sizes are rough estimates; they do not reflect size savings from automatic resource sharing between multiple regions.** For the most accurate numbers, we suggest benchmarking typical regions for your application.